# Azure Devops extension : refresh token for service endpoint with oauth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm currently building an extension and i added a service endpoint used to fetch some information from our server.

Our server uses Azure AD to authenticate, i successfully Authorize the service connection in DevOps and the information are correctly fetched. However the token used expires at some point and i would like to know how i could refresh it.

The documentation about this feature is kinda lacking and i'm a bit lost

here is the manifest json :

```
 {
            "id": "service-endpoint",
            "description": "Service endpoint to get game information",
            "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.service-endpoint-type",
            "targets": [ "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-types" ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "portal",
                "displayName": "Portal Access",
                "dataSources": [
                  {
                    "name": "AccessToken",
                    "endpointUrl": "{{{configuration.Url}}}/token",
                    "requestVerb": "Post",
                    "requestContent": "grant_type=authorization_code&code={{{#uriDataEncode 1 AuthorizationCode}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}&client_id={{{#uriDataEncode 1 configuration.ClientId}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}&client_secret={{{#uriDataEncode 1 configuration.ClientSecret}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}&redirect_uri={{{#uriDataEncode 1 RedirectUrl}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}",
                    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$",
                    "headers": [
                      {
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Game",
                    "endpointUrl": "{{{endpoint.url}}}/Studio/studios/games",
                    "requestVerb": "Get",
                    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.[*]",
                    "headers": [
                      {
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "RefreshToken",
                    "endpointUrl": "{{{configuration.Url}}}/token",
                    "requestVerb": "Post",
                    "requestContent": "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={{{#uriDataEncode 1 RefreshToken}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}&client_id={{{#uriDataEncode 1 configuration.ClientId}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}&client_secret={{{#uriDataEncode 1 configuration.ClientSecret}}}{{{/uridataencode}}}",
                    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$",
                    "headers": [
                      {
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "authenticationSchemes": [
                  {
                    "displayName": "i18n:OAuth2",
                    "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-oauth2",
                    "headers": [
                      {
                        "name": "Authorization",
                        "value": "Bearer {{{endpoint.AccessToken}}}"
                      }
                    ],
                    "authorizationUrl": "{{{configuration.Url}}}/authorize?client_id={{{configuration.ClientId}}}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={{{RedirectUrl}}}&scope=api://03105a38-d4dd-4fa1-8d6a-d1ef5c918574/API.Access",
                    "dataSourceBindings": [
                      {
                        "target": "AccessToken",
                        "dataSourceName": "AccessToken",
                        "resultTemplate": "{\"AccessToken\" : \"{{{access_token}}}\", \"RefreshToken\" : \"{{{refresh_token}}}\", \"ExpiresIn\" : \"{{{expires_in}}}\", \"TokenType\" : \"{{{token_type}}}\", \"Scope\" : \"{{{scope}}}\", \"Error\" : \"{{{error}}}\", \"ErrorDescription\" : \"{{{error_description}}}\"}"
                      },
                      {
                        "target": "RefreshToken",
                        "dataSourceName": "RefreshToken",
                        "resultTemplate": "{\"AccessToken\" : \"{{{access_token}}}\", \"RefreshToken\" : \"{{{refresh_token}}}\", \"ExpiresIn\" : \"{{{expires_in}}}\", \"TokenType\" : \"{{{token_type}}}\", \"Scope\" : \"{{{scope}}}\", \"Error\" : \"{{{error}}}\", \"ErrorDescription\" : \"{{{error_description}}}\"}"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "helpMarkDown": ""
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

Note that, to get the refresh token add the **`offline_access`** API permission:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:client_id
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code_verifier:S256
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation offline_access
client_secret:client_secret
```

**Response:**
[image]

**To refresh the access token, use the below parameters:**

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token



client_id:client_id
grant_type:refresh_token
scope:scope
client_secret:client_secret
refresh_token:refreshtoken
```

**Access token will be refreshed successfully like below:**

[image]